Predictive back issue when DialogFragment navigates to a Fragment
I am in the middle of adding full support for predictive back to my app however I encountered a weird bug while doing so.
In one area of my app I have a Fragment FragA that shows a DialogFragment DialogA. DialogA has a button to navigate to another fragment FragB. DialogA is a child fragment of FragA.
In FragB, if the user initiates the back gesture, they will briefly see the back preview (which is of FragA with DialogA). However unlike the usual predictive back behavior, the back preview immediately stops and the user is shown FragB even though the back gesture is still ongoing (i.e. the user didn't let go yet). Then when the user does trigger the back gesture nothing happens. It's as if the back gesture is somehow being cancelled.
Some additional things I noticed:

If the user issues a back fling (a very fast back gesture where predictive back does not trigger) then the back gesture works as intended.
If predictive back is disabled (eg. android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="false") then this bug does not occur.
If DialogA calls dismiss() before navigating to FragB then the bug will also not occur.

Here's a screen recording of the bug:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/NBmLTV9SC1k
If anyone knows why this occurs or how to workaround this bug please let me know. Thank you!

Ok after looking at the footage of the bug more and thinking about it I have a theory for what is happening. I think when the preview is created and the dialog fragment (DialogA) is shown, it cancels the back gesture. I'm not sure what a fix would be yet. It might not have one.

Did you try using getChildFragmentManager() and adding DialogA to the back stack?
